# Global Navigation links are missing in Site Template

Tags: 2010, navigation, site-template

I'm using SharePoint 2010, and have structured the global navigation with 6 Headings. Four of the Headings have multiple (child) links below them. These child link url's are pointing to custom libraries. I have then saved the site as a template, including all site content, but when I create a new site from my custom template, all the child links are missing.

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to use a custom menu control?

Thanks for any help,

Shannon

Answer (score -1):

by using Feature stappling we can get the global navigation.

Comment: You need to elaborate on your answer a bit more.

Comment: Should I staple all the features, or just a few, or even just one? How do I do that? What may happen to other functions relying on a stapled feature? Could you explain further since your answer don't make sense as it is. Thank you!