# SharePoint 2010 Site Template Navigation

Tags: navigation, menu-item

When I get a particular subsite with local navigation (left menu) having headings and links to pages from the subsites's Pages Library, save it as a Site Template, then create a new Site using that template, the links does not appear on left menu...

Does anyone know why??

Probably having the same issue:

[Global Navigation links are missing in Site Template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32818/global-navigation-links-are-missing-in-site-template)

Thanks,

Douglas

Comment: I've found that probably it's a bug: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5079a6ac-044b-4305-ab39-e8d6aa203571/custom-site-template-doesnt-pick-up-navigation?forum=sharepointadminprevious) . Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would try selecting "include content" when saving the template.

You may also want to try importing the template into Visual studio to poke around with it and see if the nav content is actually getting saved.